# IE7 adds blank space on word-wrap

Tags: internet-explorer, word-wrap, internet-explorer-7

I have a div inside a table cell. The div has a word-wrap:break-word. It displays fine in IE8 and Mozilla, however in IE7, the table cell extends to the assumed width of the long word that in fact is broken. As a result I have a large white space next to the div with the text, which extends the table width.

Comment: IE7 [link](http://tinypic.com/r/sxehqe/7)

Comment: IE8 [link](http://tinypic.com/r/wt6cqu/7)

Answer (score 0):

overflow:hidden on the container div nested in the table cell solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

To the CSS of the div, add:

```
{
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: normal;
max-width: < the width you need> ;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

This should give you proper word wrap.